# g++: Disable specific "deprecated or antiquated header" how?

Tags: g++, warnings, deprecated

We're using g++ 4.4.3, and one of our third-party libraries is causing the lovely error

/usr/include/c++/4.4/backward/backward_warning.h:28:2: warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.

Since it's a third-party library, I can't fix the problem, so I just want to tell the compiler to suppress this warning for the one H file that causes the problem.

I tried a few things with

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated"
```

but I can't find which warning it is to specify (there is no "-Wdeprecated").

So is there any way I can suppress this warning just for the one offending H file?  I'm hoping to do something like this:

```
// Turn off the warning
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated"
#include "BadFile.h"
// Turn the warning back on
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wdeprecated"
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out a way to do this with pragma's, only by passing -Wno-deprecated on the command line.  So if you are desperate you could try:

```
#undef __DEPRECATED

// include offensive headers here...

#define __DEPRECATED
```

But note that I definitely don't condone undef'ing system level #defines :-P